# htaccess not working with special characters?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Here's my current htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?apikey=$1&url=$2
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ index.php?apikey=$1&url=$2
```

When I go to `http://example.com/testing/google.com` it works like I want it to.

I use this PHP code:

```
<?php echo $_GET['apikey']; ?> - <?php echo $_GET['url']; ?>
```

And I get this:

```
testing - google.com
```

That just how I want it.  But I'm running into issues when there's special characters in the second parameter (they will never be in the first).  For example, I tried this:

```
http://example.com/testing/http://www.google.com/?test#again%%notworking
```

That should be displaying this on my page:

```
testing - http://www.google.com/?test#again%%notworking
```

But instead I'm getting a 404 error.  Is this possible to do with just my htaccess or do I need to change something in the PHP?

**EDIT:**

In case this helps to know, the first parameter will always be lower case letters and numbers.  It is also 32 characters long.

Comment: Start with applying proper URL encoding.

Comment: The URL needs to be passed exactly as it is, without any encoding.

Comment: Well then for one thing, the hash is not even send to the server, so you can't access its value to make it part of your rewriting; and the query string would need to be passed on explicitly as well.